# How to know which stage of a job is currently running in Apache Spark?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, bigdata

Consider I have a job as follow in Spark;

**CSV File** ==> **Filter By A Column** ==> **Taking Sample** ==> **Save As JSON**

Now my requirement is how do I know which step(*Fetching file* or *Filtering* or *Sampling*) of the job is currently executing programatically (Preferably using Java API)? Is there any way for this?

I can track Job,Stage and Task using **SparkListener** class. And it can be done like tracking a stage Id. But how to know which stage Id is for which step in the job chain.

What I want to send a notification to user when consider **Filter By A Column** is completed. For that I made a class that extends SparkListener class. But I can not find out from where I can get the name of currently executing transformation name. Is it possible to track at all?

```
public class ProgressListener extends SparkListener{

  @Override
  public void onJobStart(SparkListenerJobStart jobStart)
  {

  }

  @Override
  public void onStageSubmitted(SparkListenerStageSubmitted stageSubmitted)
  {
      //System.out.println("Stage Name : "+stageSubmitted.stageInfo().getStatusString()); giving action name only
  }

  @Override
  public void onTaskStart(SparkListenerTaskStart taskStart)
  {
      //no such method like taskStart.name()
  }
}
```

Comment: The comments to close do not seem appropriate: this is certainly a programming related question and it would also seem reasonable in breadth/scope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot exactly know when, e.g., the filter operation starts or finishes.

That's because you have transformations (`filter`,`map`,...) and actions (`count`, `foreach`,...). Spark will put as many operations into one stage as possible. Then the stage is executed in parallel on the different partitions of your input. And here comes the problem.

Assume you have several workers and the following program

**LOAD ==> MAP ==> FILTER ==> GROUP BY + Aggregation**

This program will probably have two stages: the first stage will load the file and apply the `map` and `filter`. 
Then the output will be shuffled to create the groups. In the second stage the aggregation will be performed.

Now, the problem is, that you have several workers and each will process a portion of your input data in parallel. That is, every executor in your cluster will receive a copy of your program(the current stage) and execute this on the assigned partition.

You see, you will have multiple instances of your `map` and `filter` operators that are executed in parallel, but not necessarily at the same time. In an extreme case, worker 1 will finish with stage 1 before worker 20 has started at all (and therefore finish with its `filter` operation before worker 20).

For RDDs Spark uses the [iterator model](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/05/23/apache-spark-as-a-compiler-joining-a-billion-rows-per-second-on-a-laptop.html) inside a stage. For Datasets in the latest Spark version however, they create a single loop over the partition and execute the transformations. This means that in this case Spark itself does not really know when a transformation operator finished for a single task!

Long story short:

1. You are not able the know when an operation inside a stage finishes
2. Even if you could, there are multiple instances that will finish at different times.

So, now I already had the same problem:

In our [Piglet project](https://github.com/dbis-ilm/piglet) (please allow some adverstisement ;-) ) we generate Spark code from Pig Latin scripts and wanted to profile the scripts. I ended up in inserting `mapPartition` operator between all *user operators* that will send the partition ID and the current time to a server which will evaluate the messages. However, this solution also has its limitations... and I'm not completely satisfied yet.

However, unless you are able to modify the programs I'm afraid you cannot achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider this option: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html

 It seems you can use the following rest api to get a certain job state /applications/[app-id]/jobs/[job-id]

You can set the JobGroupId and JobGroupDescription so you can track what job group is being handled. i.e. [setJobGroup](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#setJobGroup(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean))

Assuming you'll call the JobGroupId "test"

```
sc.setJobGroup("1", "Test job")
```

When you'll call the http://localhost:4040/api/v1/applications/[app-id]/jobs/[job-id]

You'll get a json with a descriptive name for that job:

```
{
  "jobId" : 3,
  "name" : "count at <console>:25",
  "description" : "Test Job",
  "submissionTime" : "2017-02-22T05:52:03.145GMT",
  "completionTime" : "2017-02-22T05:52:13.429GMT",
  "stageIds" : [ 3 ],
  "jobGroup" : "1",
  "status" : "SUCCEEDED",
  "numTasks" : 4,
  "numActiveTasks" : 0,
  "numCompletedTasks" : 4,
  "numSkippedTasks" : 0,
  "numFailedTasks" : 0,
  "numActiveStages" : 0,
  "numCompletedStages" : 1,
  "numSkippedStages" : 0,
  "numFailedStages" : 0
}
```

Comment: I didn't try because in Spark Java API there is a function that replicates each end point of the REST API. I tried all of those functions in Java API. Can you please tell me which end point of the REST API you think can solve the issue? I can then post the output for that endpoint here from Java API .

Comment: Exactly the JSON is same as I get. But how can I understand "jobId":3 is for which step like for "filterByAColumn" or "takingSample"?

Comment: Why can't you use the jobGroup or JobDescription?

Comment: The name you are getting here "count at <console>:25" which is a spark action. In my example I am also getting "Save as JSON". But the transformation name I failed to get. And regarding job group is basically a group of job and I need a particular transformation name not the whole job data. Anyway if possible just show me a json data taking my example where "name":"filter" is shown. That's all what I want.